# Fixing 301 redirect rules to not be seen as not found IIS8.5 ASP.NET

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-8

I am getting 404 when trying to access domain like `https://www.example.com` I get 404.

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
 <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect-HTTP-HTTPS-IIS">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

   <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Accessing `https://www.example.com` will get eventually to `https://example.com`. My problem is that some serves like Google webmaster tools validation can't verify the site because the page returns not found, although at the end it redirects to `https://example.com`.

`http://example.com` does show 301 redirect to `https://example.com`. It's only when I add www it doesn't show 301 redirect, although the server doe eventually redirects it to the right location.

How changes to the write rules I need to make so accessing `https://www.example.com` will be recognize as 301 redirect to `https://example.com`. I think that because of the multiple rules the page send not found.

Maybe there is a way to write it as a single rule that redirects 301 that includes both rules, so it will redirect URLs with HTTP or/and WWW to the one with HTTPS and non-WWW URLs.

**Update**: I inspected chrome Network and in the Status column, it say (canceled) for type Document and it shown on red. It might be due to IIS returning 404 because the HTTPS for domain with WWW is not certified. Is there any way around this?

Using IIS8.5 / ASP.NET 4.5

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381095/how-to-dynamically-add-rules-to-iis-rewrite-map seems to be related with

Comment: @AnilKumar I don't think so, because on the client site in Chrome dev tools, in the 'status' column it say (canceled) for Type 'document)

Comment: I think it's something that has to do with the Site binding

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create an SSL certificate for the WWW version of the site as well. Once I did it, the redirection worked as intended.

Comment: @AnilKumar thanks, wasn't trivial but eventually figured it out.